# How do select the following area after Hough line transform? (opencv)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to finding out the innermost boundaries for a pool table as shown in the following image:
[PoolCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOA7X.png)
[RequiredArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr6Nr.png)

What I did is:

- Mask green
- opening filter
- canny edges
- Hough lines
- find intersections
- find average points using kmeans clustering

Is there any way to **select** the innermost lines/points with respect to the center of pool table?

Comment: It would be better for us to understand if you **show** what exactly you mean by _innermost lines/points with respect to the center of pool table_

Comment: You already found the innermost lines! what exactly do you want now?

Comment: @Meisam Yes, I have certainly found them, but I need to **select** the required shape as in the editted post. For the required area, I need intersections of innermost lines.

Comment: @RickM. Sorry, I have editted the main post. Please refer [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr6Nr.png].

Comment: If you have the parameters to each line, what is stopping you from finding the first vertical line to the right of the center of the image, the first vertical line to the left of the center of the image, the first horizontal line above the center of the image, and the first horizontal line below the center of the image?

Comment: Do a vertical dilation (with kernel (1,11) for example) on the "edges" image. This would stick the horizontal adjacent parallel lines. Then do a horizontal dilation (kernel (11,1)). Now erode the result with kernel (11,11). This job gives you a rectangle with a thick border (the thickness of the border will be equal to the diameter of the pool's holes). Now with 'findcontour' command you have the innermost borders.